# Integration test with selenium chrome webdriver and mocha when using selenium/standalone-chrome

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use selenium-driver with nodejs and mocha for integration testing.
I have download and install selenium/standalone-chrome:latest

- docker pull selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
- docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome:latest

I use the following code to test my website by using the remove server selenium/standalone-chrome using this url http://localhost:4444/wd/hub.

```
import { assert } from "chai";
import { Builder, By, logging, WebDriver } from "selenium-webdriver";
import {
  browserType,
  chromeOptions,
  is_debugging,
  site_url,
} from "../utils/TestHelper";

var driver: WebDriver;

describe("Test App", () => {
  before(async () => {
    driver = new Builder()
      .forBrowser(browserType())
      .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions())
      .usingServer("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub")
      .build();

    const urlWeb = site_url();
    await driver.get(urlWeb);
  });

...
```

After running the test with mocha, I get the following error :

```
1) Test App
       "before all" hook for "Le Titre de la page est-il bon ?":
     WebDriverError: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
  (Session info: chrome-headless-shell=120.0.6099.109)
      at Object.throwDecodedError (C:\dev\taalal\projects\main\Test\ColiCheap\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:524:15)
      at parseHttpResponse (C:\dev\taalal\projects\main\Test\ColiCheap\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:601:13)
      at Executor.execute (C:\dev\taalal\projects\main\Test\ColiCheap\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:529:28)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at async thenableWebDriverProxy.execute (C:\dev\taalal\projects\main\Test\ColiCheap\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:745:17)
```

Can you help me please to fix this error. I use .usingServer("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub") and .usingServer("http://localhost:4444") and have always the same error.

Thanks.